# JQuery show hide div link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a toggle div that is one of many, and I need the link that toggles the div to be one color while the div is open and go back to the default color when another link on the page is clicked.
Here is the code I'm using to toggle the divs and it works perfect! When I add regular css code the link stays colored as a visited link when another link is clicked.

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).show(200);
        } else {
            $(this).hide(600);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I add to this block of code to set the color to a diferent color when selected and change it back to the default color when another link is selected... Thanks!

Comment: could you provide some HTML sample code to show your exact markup? You could create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (in my opinion) method will be to apply or remove a class using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. Then, you can format color and any other settings, using CSS.

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
}
```

And later in your CSS:

```
.highlight a { /* may need to format differently depending on your HTML structure */
    color: #ff0000; /* red */
}
```

You can also simplify your code like so:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes.highlight').removeClass("highlight"); // Remove highlight class from all `.newboxes`.
    $('#' + thechosenone ).addClass("highlight"); // Add class to just the chosen one
}
```

This code will wait for the DOM to load, then apply the "highlight" class to the first appearance of `<div class="newboxes">`:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".newboxes:first").addClass("highlight"); 
    // The :first selector finds just the first object
    // This would also work: $(".newboxes").eq(0).addClass("highlight"); 
    // And so would this: $(".newboxes:eq(0)").addClass("highlight");
    // eq(n) selects the n'th matching occurrence, beginning from zero
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to post, you beat me to it! +1

Comment: Works great! Thanks! One little thing how can I set a dive running this to be the default div?

Comment: @WebsterAlexanderIII how do you mean the default? What functionality would be associated with the default div? You could simply add `class="highlight"` in the HTML, or `class="default"` and then act upon it as such, i.e. `$(".newboxes.default").addClass("highlight").show()`

Comment: Can't get it to work... all I need is for the top div to be the highlighted color when the page opens. Then when a lower div is selected that div is highlighted and the first div is no longer highlighted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').hide(600).css('color', 'blue').find('#' + thechosenone).show(200).css('color', 'red');
}
```

Assumptions made: this class "newboxes" contains the element indicated by "thechosenone" named in the function.

CSS Class based version:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').hide(600).removeClass('linkHilightColor').find('#' + thechosenone).show(200).addClass('linkHilightColor');
}
```